# why are some js file not loading in html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the below html code and i have included few js files in it. Only jquery file loads while the other 2 files don't . Can someone point out where i am going wrong. When i check in network tab through inspect element , i see that the request for the other js files haven't hit at all.
[image]

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.1.1/css/responsive.dataTables.min.css">

<style>
div.container { max-width: 1200px }
</style>

</head>
<body>

<table id="example" class="display compact nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>First name</th>
                <th>Last name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
                <th>Extn.</th>
                <th>E-mail</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger</td>
                <td>Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
                <td>5421</td>
                <td>t.nixon@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Rhona</td>
                <td>Davidson</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>55</td>
                <td>2010/10/14</td>
                <td>$327,900</td>
                <td>6200</td>
                <td>r.davidson@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Colleen</td>
                <td>Hurst</td>
                <td>Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>39</td>
                <td>2009/09/15</td>
                <td>$205,500</td>
                <td>2360</td>
                <td>c.hurst@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>


</body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"/>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"/>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.1.1/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"/>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
        responsive: true
    } );
} );
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`<script>` is not a self closing tag. Try the following:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.1.1/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: just because modern browsers can handle them just fine, doesn't mean you should code with bad behaviors. It'll creep up on you eventually.

Answer (score 3):

`<script>` tag may have some problems with the self-closing form. Try this:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.1.1/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>
```